# Android vs iOS 7 cross platform multiplayer

Tags: terraria-mobile

I would like to know if I can play cross-platform multiplayer between the latest Android version and the iOS 7 version of Terraria.

Comment: You know, i was gonna edit this, but I have honestly no idea what you're asking after rubbing the dust out of my eyes and reading again. What platform are you trying to play the game on? You cannot use the Android version on iOS...

Comment: @Kaizerwolf - I don't think the question is about running on a different platform, but whether he can play multiplayer vs. Android players on the iOS 7 version.

Comment: I'm using an iphone and my brother is playing on a andriod an the latest version of the game on the AppStore is for ios8 and my brother has the latest and I have to get an older version to play it on my iphone 4

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, the latest iOS version of Terraria should run on iOS 7. This version is the same as the Android version on Google Play, and should support cross-platform multiplayer.

Comment: I'm using an iphone and my brother is playing on a andriod an the latest version of the game on the AppStore is for ios8 and my brother has the latest and I have to get an older version to play it on my iphone 4

Comment: Fair - I don't have iOS 7 and am basing my information on the patch notes.